# Reduce Dimensons when converting list to array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes

I want to reduce the dimensions of an array after converting it to a list

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
print a.shape
b = np.array([[1],[3,4]])
print b.shape
```

Output:

```
(2, 2)
(2,)
```

I want a to have the same shape as b i.e. (2,)

Comment: What exactly do you want `a` to look like after the transformation? If you want it to be `[[1,2],[3,4]]`, it has to be two-dimensional. `list(a)` would convert your array into `[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]`. Is that what you want?

Comment: After the transformation I want it to look like  [[1,2],[3,4]]

Comment: I want it to look like that but have the structure of b. The second dimension should be undefined. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. Why do you want that?

Comment: I will later use vstack() to join the arrays, if the shape doesn't match vstack ()does not work proeperly

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4], None])[:2]
>>> a
array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=object)
>>> a.shape
(2,)
```

Works, though is probably the wrong way to do it (I'm a numpy newb).

Comment: Though, I'd put the None in the first cell, give numpy a chance to short-circuit the depth search.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what `b` is?

```
b = np.array([[1],[3,4]])
print(repr(b))

array([[1], [3, 4]], dtype=object)
```

`b` is a 1d array with 2 elements, each a list.  `np.array` does this way because the 2 sublists have different length, so it can't create a 2d array.

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
print(repr(a)) 

array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Here the 2 sublists have the same length, so it can create a 2d array.  Each element is an integer.  `np.array` tries to create the highest dimensional array that the input allows.

Probably the best way to create another array like `b` is to make a copy, and insert the desired lists.

```
a1 = b.copy()
a1[0] = [1,2]
# a1[1] = [3,4]
print(repr(a1))

array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=object)
```

You have to use this convoluted method because you trying to do something 'unnatural'.

You comment about using `vstack`.  Both work:

```
In [570]: np.vstack((a,b))   # (3,2) array
Out[570]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [[1], [3, 4]]], dtype=object)

In [571]: np.vstack((a1,b))   # (2,2) array
Out[571]: 
array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
       [[1], [3, 4]]], dtype=object)
```

Your array `b` is little more than the original list in an array wrapper.  Is that really what you need?  The 2d `a` is a normal `numpy` array.  `b` is an oddball construction.

Comment: Thanks your comments are really helpful. True it mostly works as a list, but it allows me to add a column of empty lists in the array. Which I could not achieve with a list