# Can I construct a numpy object zero-d array from its value in a single expression?

Tags: python, numpy

These all work (ie, have `.shape == ()`):

```
np.array(1, dtype=object)
np.array("foo", dtype=object)
np.array(object(), dtype=object)
```

But this does not:

```
np.array((0, 0), dtype=object)  # .shape == (2,)
```

I can achieve this with two assignments as:

```
def make_scalar(x):
    value = np.empty((), dtype=object)
    value[()] = x
    return value

make_scalar((0, 0))  # .shape == ()
```

Is there a builtin function that will allow me to create this 0d array in a single expression (for arbitrary scalar values)?

Comment: Tried `numpy.full(shape=(), fill_value=(0, 0), dtype=object)`. Didn't work.

Comment: @user2357112: yep, that was actually the thing that led to this question

Comment: Can't you just do: `x=object(); np.array(x, dtype=object).shape`? It is a singleton array with the arbitrary value of `x` -- whatever you want that object to be

Comment: @dawg: Did you read my question? Try that with `x = (0, 0)`, and you'll be as dissapointed as I am

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Title was misleading, updated. I want it to contain a specific value

Comment: I'm confused. Is your issue that you are you specifically trying to use a tuple as a 'scalar' value? If so the issue is that the array constructor reinterprets tuples within the constructor as "array_like objects", but assignment after the fact is fine as long as the dtype is compatible. so you can do something like `a = numpy.empty((), dtype=object)[()] = (0,0)`

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Yes, I am trying to use a tuple as a scalara value. I don't think that chained assignment works, but the gist of it is the same as the function in my question

Comment: Yes exactly. My point is that you cannot avoid the constructor reinterpreting the tuple, so you have no option but to perform assignment at some point in your workflow to achieve this. (your accepted answer essentially suggests the same). I just reduced your approach to a oneliner to demonstrate a "single expression" as requested in your question (and yes, chained assignment works, though obviously you're free to put parentheses around the second `=` for clarity).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: No, the chained assignment does not work, as `type(a)` is `tuple`, not `ndarray`

Comment: ah, you're right, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered this kind of question of a number of times, when people want to make a object array containing lists or tuples.  All that's different here is you want to do this with a 0d array.

For example: [Reduce Dimensons when converting list to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281481/reduce-dimensons-when-converting-list-to-array)

This question contrasts:

```
 np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])  # (2,2) int
 np.array([[1],[3,4]])    # (2,) object
```

Making a (2,) object from the first list requires the create and fill approach.  `np.array(...)` insists on drilling down into a nested iterable  as far as it can go.  It's trained, so to speak, to create as high a dimensional array as it can.  It will iterate on lists and tuples, but not on dictionaries or sets.

`np.array` takes a `ndmin` parameter, but not a `ndmax` one.  I believe there is some github issue about array creator that would limit that depth.

For now, creating a 'empty' object array of the right dimension, and filling it is best.  And it's easy to get errors when filling, such as broadcasting or setting with sequences ones.

There's nothing wrong with your `make_scalar` function.  This isn't the kind of operation where speed matters.  So your own function is just as pretty as a builtin one.

Another thought - `scipy.io.loadmat` returns a lot of single element object arrays.  It does this to represent MATLAB structures and cells. We could look at its code to see if that developer uses anything clever.

Relevant github issues:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5933 Enh: Object array creation function

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6070 Please Deprecate creation of numpy arrays for arbitrary objects